# How to get IDs of checked records from list view

Tags: lightning-aura-components, custom-object, list-view

I need to get Ids of checked records of Custom object's list view page.

Custom button using visualforce page can get it, but it is not good solution.

The best is I can do it from utility bar component.

Is there any such method?

Comment: Hi @Hayato, may I know why it is not a good solution a visual-force button?

Comment: Thank you for the question. my boss think visual-force is old style and it may be abolished. moreover, our team usually using lightning aura component, so there is less people who can maintenance visual-force.